# Can you just tell, What is the use of iframe in asp.net?

Tags: html

I want to know the use of iframe in asp.net.
 I am new in asp.net.help me

Comment: iframe is an HTML tag. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET specifically.

Comment: The only use I'd see for it in asp.net would be loading an external site into your application (maybe as a quick/easy way to display Google Maps or similar).  If you want to load content from your application into another page, you should use user controls.  If this content needs to be dynamic, use a placeholder and load the user control into the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iframes have many, many uses. They are used for ads, asynchronous (kinda) communication, controlled-browsing, and more. None of these things are necessarily specific to .net.

I'd like to encourage you read w3schools for additional information: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

Iframe defines an inline frame. it is an html tag like div,span etc. One of the advantage of iframe is it can be a target of other links. you can also show html content(from any external source) in iframe. more information about iframe is [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe.html)